# Git repos over 2 machines, eclipse wont detect new projects

Tags: linux, windows, eclipse, git, ocaml

I have an **ubuntu** and **windows** machine. I'm trying to push/pull with both at a given time. The problem is that when i create a project, commit&push and then pull on the other machine, eclipse wont detect the project automatically or even if i import it manually.

The git repository is the workspace itself. I've tried fiddling with the .gitignore file which is global to the workspace such as allowing .path and .project, but all it did is mess up the build paths of the **OcalIDE(OCaml)**.

I'm wondering if there's a possible way of achieving this or do i have to resort to using **EGit**?.

Comment: Are you sure that no file needed by your IDE is missing in your Git repository?

Comment: Remove all IDE file from  the repository just put source code inside. Then configure your IDE on the both machines. that is

Comment: @RichouHunter the thing is, as soon as I push a file needed for the IDE, the paths get re-written and it brakes everything. So would need to do it without.

Comment: @Ôrel that might work in a single project, so i would probably need to make a project myself on both machines if i wanted a new one then every time.

Comment: You have just to do it once on each machine not every time. Your IDE file are relative to the machine not to the project, think about if you are several people working on the project, it is exactly the same.